# How do eclipse core plugins update eclipse ui plugins?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipses plugin architecture, a core or model plugin exists to handle backend, and a ui plugin handles presentation. The UI plugin depends on the core plugin, but the core plugin does not depend on the UI plugin. So the core plugin does not see any types that are in the UI plugin.

How can I notify my debug SWT widgets of changes that occur in the core plugins? SelectionListener will not be valid because I want my widgets to update immediately as new changes come in, not when something is selected in the window workbench. I do not see how a general/simple even listener can be registered to the model object as that is where the model object is created. The GUI is event based, so unless it somehow just wakes up every few milliseconds and seeks out the last IDebugTarget and registers one of its views as a listener, I don't see how this is going to work. And that would be a bad design smell (manual polling).

Comment: Don't you just want to raise an event when anything *interesting* happens in core and then register event listeners to core from UI so that the UI gets notified when anything interesting happens?

Comment: Yes. However I ran into an egg before the chicken problem wrt adding the listener to the core. I saw no practical hook from the UI to run when the launch was completed. What I discovered was to 1) create an activator from my plugin and override the `start` method. 2) add `DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().addLaunchListener(this)` to start so that I can listen to new launches being created and 3) get my custom debug target from `launch.getDebugtarget()` and 4) inject the custom event listeners (ones that push what model objects I want, when I want them) to my core/debug target.

Comment: OK then, you need to be more specific.  Show some code snippets of what you are trying to do.  What events are you trying to listen to? What plugins are involved? What model are you interacting with?